# DQL Query with Associations?

Tags: doctrine, dql

I am working on a webapp that has three entities: User, Project, and Todo.

Every Todo has a many-to-one relationship with Projects.
Todos also have a many-to-many relationship to Users.

What I am trying to do is retrieve projects that contain a todo that has been assigned to a given user.

My code is as follows. $id has been set to the user_id I want to retrieve projects for

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$projects = $em->createQuery("SELECT p FROM projects p INNER JOIN p.todos t WITH t.assigned_to = :id")
    ->setParameter('id', $id)
    ->getResult();
```

Whenever I run this query I get the following error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 79 near 'assigned_to =': Error: Invalid
>   PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or
>   SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updated:

As the assigned_to relation is a many to many relation pointed out in the comments there is no actual field assigned_to for the comparision.

You have to join the association:

```
SELECT p 
FROM projects p 
INNER JOIN p.todos t 
INNER JOIN t.assigned_to a
WHERE a.id = :id
```

I am using the WHERE condition as thats what I am accustomed to, as I learned from you WITH is also supported and might work, too ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the WITH clause is supported. It can be found in one of the Doctrine examples listed [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html). And when I replace `WITH t.assigned_to = :id"` with a condition that doesn't use a foreign key (such as `WITH t.description = 'Say hi'"`) the query works fine.

Comment: Also, I did try using the WHERE clause and ran into the same problems.

Comment: @JamesKirkwood hm… what is your mapping of assigned_to? is this a collection of multiple values or a single value?

Comment: assigned_to can be mapped to several Users, it is a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @JamesKirkwood thanks for clarification, I updated my answer, give it a try